# Calling javascript onmouseout event in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to call javascript `onmouseout` event in javascript code?

I.e.:

```
var div=document.getElementById('new');
if(div.mouseout)
  document.getElementById('new').style.visibility='hidden';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
var div = document.getElementById("new");
div.onmouseout = function (e)
{
    this.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: Yeah true i have put an alert inside the loop but it doesnt show up...................

Comment: It's not a loop, and you'll need to show us your full code if you want us to debug it (edit it into your question).

Comment: i have edited my question.
i.e, on mouseout i want to set document.getElementById('new').style.visibility='hidden';

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var div=document.getElementById('new');
    div.onmouseout = function(){
        this.style.visibility='hidden';
    };
};
```

You can use `this` keyword to specify the current element, no need to again fetch the element using `document.getElementById`.

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ijoju)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.getElementById("new");
div.mouseout = function()
{
this.style.display='none';
}
```